# Hide imageview if it is blocked by gridview item?

Tags: android

I am attempting to hide an imageview only if an item in the gridview blocks it.

The gridview is set to match_parent and the imageview sits in the bottom right so realistically it means that once we get to around 8 items it should be hidden. I know I could create some static logic to hide items after a certain number but that wouldn't be effective for all devices.

Is there a collision type or any way to check if a view is blocked by a sub view (a gridview item).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved with a bit of a weird solution:

(C# Xamarin - can easily be translated to Java)

```
var size = this.connectionGrid.ChildCount;
        var shouldHide = false;
        var logoRect = new Rect();
        this.appLogo.GetHitRect(logoRect);

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
        { 
            var gridChild = this.connectionGrid.GetChildAt(i);
            var childRect = new Rect();
            gridChild.GetHitRect(childRect);

            if (childRect.Intersect(logoRect))
            {
                shouldHide = true;
            }
        } 

        this.appLogo.Visibility = shouldHide ? ViewStates.Invisible : ViewStates.Visible;
```